# SQL current timestamp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trigger, timestamp, row-modification-time

I have made a featureclass for a utility company where they can register measures set up to mitigate problems with rats, called "mitigation measure". From this feature class it is possible to state if the current mitigation measure has been removed or not. This field is named "Removed" and it is a domain value with possibilities "Yes", "No" and "Not set".

I now wish to create a sql trigger that can update a time field called "DateRemove" with the current timestamp for the moment the utility company changes the field "Removed" from "No" to "Yes". But only when this exact change happens, not when other changes occur within the feature class.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hey Phil. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Is that information enough?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462300/trigger-and-update-to-a-row-in-sql-server-after-its-been-updated) is what you're looking for.

Comment: see @NelsonCasanova link, just add 'AND removed = 'Yes'' to where clause in (select 1 from inserted where )

Comment: So something like this: ALTER TRIGGER [sonfor_ags].[trg_date] 
ON [sonfor_ags].[MitigationMeasure]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET DateRemove = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM [sonfor_ags].[MitigationMeasure] AS t
   INNER JOIN inserted AS i
   ON t.ID = i.ID
   AND t.Removed = 1;
END
GO       , where 1="yes"

Comment: I changed a few things so that it ended up like this: Create TRIGGER [sonfor_ags].[trg_date] 
ON [sonfor_ags].[MitigationMeasure]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET DateRemove = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM [sonfor_ags].[MitigationMeasure] AS t
   INNER JOIN inserted AS i
   ON t.OBJECTID = i.OBJECTID
   AND i.Removed = 1;
END
GO
--> and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: @KristianBirchvaldJensen - How about posting your solution in the comment above as the Answer to your Question.

Answer (score 1):

I changed a few things so that it ended up like this:

```
Create TRIGGER [sonfor_ags].[trg_date] ON [sonfor_ags].[MitigationMeasure] 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    UPDATE t SET DateRemove = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    FROM [sonfor_ags].[MitigationMeasure] AS t 
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON t.OBJECTID = i.OBJECTID 
       AND i.Removed = 1; END GO
```

and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes and no.  If you make any changes to MitigationMeasure after removed is set to 1 it will continue to update your column.  Add a check to see if the DateRemoved is NULL if you don't want it to continue to move forward.